# Launch Spark-Shell (Scala) from Windows and Set Working Directory Path

Tags: windows, scala, apache-spark, command-line

I've installed Spark using RStudio's sparklyr package, and returned the path via:

```
# library(sparklyr)
# spark_home_dir()
```

Now I want to launch the `spark-shell` from Windows command shell, and this works fine.

```
start C:\\Users\\eyeOfTheStorm\\AppData\\Local\\rstudio\\spark\\Cache\\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\bin\\spark-shell
```

But when I try to set the working directory to my desktop, so I can read files from there, it doesn't point correctly using `:load` to point to the working directory.

```
start C:\\Users\\eyeOfTheStorm\\AppData\\Local\\rstudio\\spark\\Cache\\spark-2.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\\bin\\spark-shell :load C:\\Users\\eyeOfTheStorm\\Desktop\\WorkingDir
```

And from Scala, this should confirm the working directory as Desktop...

```
def pwd = System.getProperty("user.dir"); println(pwd)
```

But it only returns `C:\Users\eyeOfTheStorm`. I would like it to return `C:\\Users\\eyeOfTheStorm\\Desktop`. Any idea how to do this in a single Windows command?

Answer (score 3):

in the repl session you lunched, enter this line:

```
scala> System.setProperty("user.dir", "C:\\Users\\eyeOfTheStorm\\Desktop")
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 1):

The current working directory (cwd) at the time the JVM starts will be the cwd for that JVM for the rest of its life. It cannot be changed by changing System properties. So 7kemZmani's solution will not work.

Just cd into the intended working directory **before** starting the shell

```
cd C:\my\working\dir
start "$SPARK_HOME\bin\spark-shell"
```